# How do I wrap the location-list by default (without turning on wrap for files)?

Tags: wrapping, plugin-syntastic, location-list

I think this should be a quick answer, but I can't figure it out from `:help location-list` and my Google searches seem to highlight that I may not know the correct terms to look for.

For the sake of this scenario, lets say I'm using syntastic to run `hlint` on a Haskell file, and it's adding things to the location-list.

In my `.vimrc`, I have `set nowrap` on (that's the way I like it) but I am imagining that since the `location-list` is a separate pane that I could probably target it with something akin to `autocmd [???] location-list set wrap`.

Is there a way? (I would especially appreciate a link to the docs about this because I think that might help me grok stuff inthe future.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can indeed use an autocommand:

```
augroup MyStuff
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType qf setlocal wrap
augroup END
```

This will affect the quickfix window, too, but I presume that would be desirable.

You can find a sort of oblique reference to this in the documentation by opening `:help location-list` and then searching for `filetype`.

Even better, use Vim's `after` directory. Create a file:

```
.vim/after/ftplugin/qf.vim
```

With the contents:

```
setlocal wrap
```

This is documented in `:help after-directory` and, perhaps more relevantly, in `:help ftplugin-overrule`.

Comment: :chef-kiss: perfect!

Comment: Whoops, forgot to select as answer. I have since rectified the situation.